Where is the SAML Assertion sent by the IdP in case of SAML2.0 flow?
I was going through the flow for SAML 2.0 and came across the following sequence diagram on Wikipedia for SAML2.0.

I'm migrating from an OAuth2 based auth to SAML2.0 .
One major difference was that OAuth2 returns the token to the User Agent (Browser) while SAML2.0 returns it directly to the Service Provider.
In the diagram though it says that the XHTML form (the assertion) is returned to the User Agent. I understand that the assertion can be sent to any callback URL.
What is the best practice for implementing SAML 2.0 in my app. Should the assertion go to the User Agent(Browser) or Service Provider (Backend Service) ?

One major difference was that OAuth2 returns the token to the User Agent (Browser) while SAML2.0 returns it directly to the Service Provider. False. SAML2 token is also returned to the browser which in turn POSTs it to the Service Provider. I understand that the assertion can be sent to any callback URL. Not really, in most cases the return url for a Service Provider is preconfigured at the Identity Provider and is sent only to this preconfigured address.
